# What is the first parameter (k) of the callback to jQuery.each used for?

Tags: jquery, variables

in this piece of code, K is never mentioned on, so, what is it there for? I took this piece of code from a video lecture I saw. Why have k there? does it hold some kind of information in the given code?

```
var elems = [$ventfade, $venthoverm $spans];

$.each(elems, function(k,v){
  if (v.data('currently') != 'showing'){
    v.stop();
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the current index of the element. It's not used in your example but the next parameter (`v`) is, so the first parameter must be specified. If you had only `function(v){ ...` then v would have a different meaning.

See also http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 5):

k stands for key in a hash.

It means

```
$.each(elems, function(key,value){
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it accepts index in array while iterating. Look [documentation on each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 1):

It's the index of the current element, as such it may be useful in other situations when you want to know which element in the array you're currently looking at within the `each`

Take a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), for example, iterating over a simple array:

```
$.each([52, 97], function(index, value) { 
alert(index + ': ' + value); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `k` and `v` are the parameters of your function, and they are supplied by jQuery's `each` function.

Even though you only need the second parameter, you have to declare the first too, otherwise you won't be able to access the second.